# How can I work out the formula for Wind Downwarde6b

Tags: triangles

I want to write a step by step guide on how to do Wind up and Wind down calculations using the CRP / E6B.

I have a prototype Excel but need to work out the 25 drift @ 114 and how to loop until the drifts match [G22]

Wind up is working using

B26 is `=B11+DEGREES(ASIN(B14*SIN(RADIANS(B13-B11))/B12))`

B27 is `=B12*COS(RADIANS(B26-B11))-B14*COS(RADIANS(B13-B11))`

Once this is working i can show each step required using actual numbers

https://e6bx.com/e6b/
[image]

Comment: Non-understandable right from the beginning. It looks to have something to do with wind, but what ? Connection with tag "triangles" ???

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Drift_(navigation)

Comment: As the word "drift" was well hidden in your text (and not present in your title), nobody here can imagine what are all these very technical terms CRP, E6B, B26, etc. about (B26 is for me a WWII bomb plane...)

Comment: You need to remember that other people cannot see into your head to know what you are thinking about, nor are likely to have been studying exactly the same thing and so would be familiar with exactly the same jargon as you, and thus need no explanation. You even need to recall that words in English usually have multiple disparate meanings, particularly when written, which must be determined from context. "Wind up" and "Wind down" suggests "wind" is used as in "wind a clock". "drift" suggests "wind" means "movement of air". If the latter, what do you mean by "wind up" and "wind down"?

Comment: You also need to consider "Is this a question about mathematics" and thus appropriate for this forum, or is it a question about physics, or engineering, or programming, or other things, and thus appropriate for other forums.